membership application form w/o access to civicim
We are evaluating the use of civicrm. Regarding data security we have a need vor very high standards, so the policy is never to store any personal information on a computer that is directly accessible from the web for a prolonged amount amount of time.
Usually what we do with form entries is:

on submit: encrypt it (using asynchronous encryption)
store the encrypted data to a dedicated folder
have our internal systems pull the data from there every other minutes to our internal systems and delete it from the server thereafter
decrypt and store it on our systems

Usually we use a RestAPI system to perform whichever task would otherwise be performed by the (live) form on the website to store the data locally.
Now, we would like to know: is there a proper/testet/conceivable way to make this happen with civicrm, esp. is there a proper API interface for civicim, and how cumbersome would that probably be?
I'd appreciate any input and advice greatly!

Yes, there is a very capable API - see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/ (Use APIv4 for any new work.)
Your process could continue as is and the very last part 'store it on our systems' would use the API to create the membership (and maybe contact as well).
Alternatively you could look the FormProcessor extension to process the form data.
If you are open to changing the first 3 steps, then look at the CiviMRF extension (also works with FormProcessor).
Another option to consider is Inlay & FormProcessor

Maybe add CiviProxy? https://docs.civicrm.org/civiproxy/en/latest/
